# Specify the country to be searched in Android GeoCoder?

Tags: android, google-geocoder, android-location

I can [specify a square](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) where the Geocoder shall search in, but I found no way to specify a certain country. Unfortunately, my country isn't quadrangular ;( What should I do? Use another reverse geocoding service?

*I'd want to build a search box where the user can search for a city (with auto suggestion). On every keystroke the current search query is going to be delivered to the Geocoder.*

Comment: Is there a problem with using the smallest rectangle that surrounds your country?

Comment: then there are still many other countries in the rectangle

Comment: I ended up doing following: 1. add the country code to the string like ", DE" 2. set the bounds 3. filter the result by checking the country code That worked for me pretty well. Didnt want to parse the json. It also breaks the rules of the terms of use of google if I use this API posted by bramp in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If it's any help, the official Geocoding API can do [regional biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes). It would require you to use their web API instead of the Android API.